# 'npm run dev' in vue.js is not working nor giving an error

Tags: npm, vuejs3, vite

I've made a project last week and I used to run this command `npm run dev` to open up a localhost.

But now I don't know what happened I'm just using it like usual but it won't work anymore,

And it doesn't give an error too so I don't know where/what the problem is,

When I use it, it doesn't open up a localhost it stays like this:

```
PS D:\APP\Front-End Development\Smart-Z Calculator V1.0> npm run dev

> smart-z-calculator-v1-0@0.0.0 dev
> vite
```

This is package.json file:

```
{
"name": "smart-z-calculator-v1-0",
"version": "0.0.0",
"private": true,
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
"dev": "vite",
"build": "vite build",
"preview": "vite preview"
},
"dependencies": {
 "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.1",
 "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
 "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
 "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
 "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.5",
 "vue": "^3.3.11",
 "vue-cli": "^2.9.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.2",
 "vite": "^5.0.10"
}
}
```

I'm using Vuejs 3, npm 9.8.1 if that helps,

By the way I tried to wait for it, but nothing else happened,

If anybody has faced this one before, feel free to leave a comment.

Thanks

Comment: we need your package.json's script section to see what command is invoked by npm run dev

Comment: re-published check it out

Comment: it's not clear why you have both `vite` and `vue-cli` as they're opposing build tools.  which one are you actually using? do you have a vite.config.js or vue.config.js file?

Comment: This is vite config file, I'm using vite not vue-cli :                                                      import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})